# have a raw input in a variable?

Tags: python, string, debugging, raw-input

For a project I need to have a program ask a contests name, use the name in another question.
The Code below works.
The Main problem is that I need the time entered as a value and saved so I can calculate it later, but print in a line that says `time = """""` , doesn't work.
Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

```
def main():
    print "~*~*~*~*~*~ Timbuktu Archery Contest ~*~*~*~*~*~"
    archerList = [] #list
    name = raw_input ("Enter contestants first name: ")
    s = str(name)
    archerList.append(name)
    print "Enter time (in milliseconds) for " + s , raw_input (": ")

main()
```

Comment: can you show the exact error msg

Comment: `s=str(name)` is redundant.  `name` is already a string.

Answer (score 3):

i think you need to do

```
t  = raw_input ("Enter time (in milliseconds) for %s :" % s)
```

Answer (score 1):

For `raw_input` returns a string value,
So `x = raw_input()` will assign the string of what the user has input to `x`.
See [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) for docs  of `raw_input`.
For your archerslist, you may want to use a dictionary instead as then you can access the "time" with the name of the archer.
See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for dictionary documentation
You can use dictionaries like this:

```py
def main():
    print "~*~*~*~*~*~ Timbuktu Archery Contest ~*~*~*~*~*~"
    archers = {}
    while True: # get inputs till user inputs empty string.
        name = raw_input ("Enter contestants first name: ")
        if name == '':
            break
        while True: # get input till ttime can be converted to an int.
            ttime = raw_input ("Enter time (in milliseconds) for %s :" % name)
            try:
                ttime = int(ttime)
            except ValueError: # error handling
                print 'Invalid input, Enter a number'
            else:
                break
        archers[name] = ttime # assign values to the dictionary
    return archers # return dictionary value
```